# Is there any way to workaround the "error code 80072f0d" when syncing against an Exchange server?

Tags: email, sync, exchange

At our work the certificate for connecting to our Exchange server has expired, generating a

> Error code 80072f0d

when I'm trying to sync my work emails.

Is there anyway to make the sync work anyway? I tried to connect an Android device to sync against the same server, and that works without any problems.

I know that the "correct" way to solve this is to contact our IT-department and ask them to renew the certificate. But since I already done this and they seem to ignore me I would like to find a way to sync my work emails from the Exchange server anyway. Since it works on the Android device even though the certificate is expired it seems like it should be possible to make it work from the WP7.5 device also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These certificates are used for a reason and if they are expired they should be renewed or otherwise you could just as well just remove them.

that Android doesn't care about these certificates is a flaw in Android instead of this being a problem of Windows Phone. (ok for you as a user it isn't.)

So back to your IT-department is my advice

Comment: Yep. I will just have to nag a bit. :)